# $.ajax request not returning full variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, variables, callback

The code below is my $.ajax request, the return value should be a 'select' tag filled, though I keep getting an empty 'select' tag, I've checked the php page it calls to, even inputted variables via the URL to check it's working and it does work...on the php page but it wont forward the dropdown list along with the 'select' tag. anyone have any ideas?

```
function sendCategoryRequest() {
  var URL = $('#indStore1').val();
  var site = $('#site').val();
    if ($.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "../dashboard/sendgcr.php",
                data: { URL: URL, site: site },
                dataType: "html",
                timeout: 4000,
                success: function (response) {
                           if (response != "") {
                             document.getElementById('LCatC').innerHTML = response;
                             alert(response);
                           } else {
                             alert("Nothing came back :(");
                           }
                         }
              })) {
    } else {
      alert("Proccessing Stage 2 Failed!");
    }
}// end sendCategoryRequest
```

Here's my response (in HTML format):

```
<span style = 'float: left;
           clear: left;
           margin-right: 20px;'>
  Category (Leaf): 
</span>
<select id = 'LCat'
    style = 'float: left;'>
</select>
```

It should be:

```
<span style = 'float: left;
           clear: left;
           margin-right: 20px;'>
  Category (Leaf): 
</span>
<select id = 'LCat'
    style = 'float: left;'>
  <option value = '(value recieved here)'>(Name recieved here)</option> // repeated until no more options present in the arrays
</select>
```

Comment: Apart from anything else, what makes you think `$.ajax` returns a boolean? And why not use jQuery to populate the `select`?

Comment: Because I'm calling 2 arrays which need to be inserted into the option tags and to my knowledge I can't callback multiple variables

Comment: Again, what makes you think `$.ajax` returns a boolean? And if you can use `innerHTML`, you can use jQuery's `html` which is probably going to be more reliable (as it handles some browser eccentricities for you). Recommend reading [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com).

Comment: Also, what is the text your PHP returns?

Comment: it should be: 

`code`<span style = 'float: left;
        clear: left;
        margin-right: 20px;'>
  Category (Leaf): 
</span>
<select id = 'LCat'
 style = 'float: left;'>
  <option value = '(option value here)'>(option name here)</option>
  \\(repeated until no more options)
</select>`code`

Comment: it returns

<span style = 'float: left; clear: left; margin-right: 20px;'> Category (Leaf): </span> <select id = 'LCat' style = 'float: left;'>
</select>

Comment: just edited to show the response and what it should be

Comment: Sounds like an error in the PHP. The jQuery part sending the data is fine *provided* the fields really have `id` attributes (**not** `name` attributes!) matching what you've used (`"indStore1"` and `"site"`). Your best bet is to walk through with a debugger, there's [no excuse](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/03/no-excuse.html) for not using a client-side debugger in 2012. :-) (And again: Read up on the `$.ajax` docs for what it returns.)

Comment: I run it in the PHP and it shows the correct response, but it doesn't seem to return the response :(